# Are UART, SPI, I2C, etc implementations generic?

Tags: embedded

Is it possible to create one file, say for example uart.c to be generic, so that I can call the uart functions for different microcontrollers, say for example avr and arm? or is it a must that for every microcontroller I will have to create the the uart functions from scratch?

Comment: Several frameworks have already solved this. To name a popular one: [Arduino](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-API).

Comment: You can still abstract basic functions like read, write, open, close (use function pointers for example). Depending on your protocol you keep header same while source (C) you can easily exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hardware implementations and register interfaces across different vendors certainly differ.  ARM do not make MCUs they licence the core - the peripherals are not defined by the core so even amongst ARM devices the peripheral implementations differ between vendors.

What you can do is define a common device-layer interface and implement that interface for each device family you need, then you can reuse the application layer code across architectures.

The alternative is to stick with a common family.  AVR for example covers a wide range of devices and the peripherals generally are common across the range.  Similarly STM32 (ARM Cortex-M) devices share common peripherals across the range.

So the answer is no, but you can deal with that by abstracting the hardware (or the vendor supplied abstraction or device layer).

For a UART you might use stdio as your abstraction layer and access the device via `fprintf`, `fputchar`, `fread`, `fwrite` etc.  Though typically you'd build that on a lower level layer too.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) that acts as a common interface for all hardware of the same kind. A correctly designed HAL allows portable application-layer code, which is the sole purpose of having one.

The HAL should be in the form of an API library that then acts as a header file template for how the drivers should be designed, the simplest form of "polymorphism". The application programmer calls the HAL, and the MCU-specific functions in the driver will then get called.

In case of UART you might have an init function taking baudrate, stop bit, parity, handshaking etc as parameters. And then a read function and a write function, with some error handling. Overrun and framing errors are universal, for example. It is then up to the specific driver for MCU "x" to implement itself according to your specified HAL.

Generally, one should not create abstaction layers needlessly though. It is quite qualified work and easy to get wrong. If you don't need portability or code re-use between projects, there's no obvious need for a HAL and you could as well call the driver directly from the application code.

Comment: Some examples of incorrectly designed HALs are the big libraries provided by ST, Atmel and others, where their so-called "HAL" is just a bunch of wrappers around register access. Rather than a MCU-independent function hiding away the whole hardware peripheral functionality and not just the register writes. Notably, silicon vendors have very little interest in providing means for you to port away from their MCU, so they have a self-interest in providing these crappy would-be "HALs".